# "LIKE" query on table with Foreign Key assigned to multiple tables based upon relationship type

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-key-relationship, laravel-query-builder

My issue has three tables: "comments", "users" & "company_contacts"

The "comments" table has two columns: `"company_contact (INT)"` & `"company_contact_kind (String)"`

`comments.company_contact` is either assigned to `users.id` or `company_contacts.id` based upon either if `comments.company_contact_kind = 'contact'` or if `comments.company_contact_kind = 'user'`

Here is my query:

```
$data['comments'] = Comment::join('users', 'comments.creator_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('users AS user_contacts', 'comments.company_contact', '=', 'user_contacts.id')
        ->join('company_contacts', 'company_contacts.id', '=', 'comments.company_contact')
        ->where('comments.commentable_type', $request->type)
        ->where('comments.commentable_id', $request->company_id)
        ->where(function($query) use ($request){
        $query->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('users.first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('users.last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('user_contacts.first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('user_contacts.last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('company_contacts.first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('company_contacts.last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('comments.contact_type', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%');
        })
        ->orderBy('comments.created_at', 'DESC')
        ->select('comments.*')
        ->get();
```

**My Issue:**
When searching for a specific Comment Contact, because I reference both users and company contacts within my query and both equal `comments.company_contact`, if I search for either the first or last name of `company_contacts.id`, it'll return results with `users.id` as the `comments.company_contact` because `comments.company_contact` references both users and company_contacts.

Is there a way to set a condition within the query for something more intuitive?

**Solved:**

Thanks to the answer proposed by @cmerriman, I was able to tweak the answer and solve it by the following query:

```
$data['comments'] = Comment::join('users', 'comments.creator_id', '=', 'users.id')

        ->leftJoin('users AS user_contacts', function ($join) {
            $join->where('comments.company_contact_kind', '=', 'user')
                 ->on('comments.company_contact', '=','user_contacts.id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('company_contacts', function ($join) {
            $join->where('comments.company_contact_kind', '=', 'contact')
                 ->on('comments.company_contact', '=','company_contacts.id'); 
        })
        ->where('comments.commentable_type', $request->type)
        ->where('comments.commentable_id', $request->company_id)
        ->where(function($query) use ($request){
        $query->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('users.first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('users.last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('user_contacts.first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('user_contacts.last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('company_contacts.first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('company_contacts.last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('comments.contact_type', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
            ->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%');
        })
        ->orderBy('comments.created_at', 'DESC')
        ->select('comments.*')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Laravel, but if I am reading the docs correctly, try changing

```
->join('users AS user_contacts', 'comments.company_contact', '=', 'user_contacts.id')
->join('company_contacts', 'company_contacts.id', '=', 'comments.company_contact')
```

to

```
->join('users AS user_contacts', function ($join) {
            $join->on('comments.company_contact', '=','user_contacts.id')
                 ->andOn('comments.company_contact_kind, '=', 'user'); } )
->join('companyusers AS user_contacts', function ($join) {
            $join->on('comments.company_contact', '=','company_contacts.id')
                 ->andOn('comments.company_contact_kind, '=', 'contact'); } )
```